# Selection based on Ranking and Weighting in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I  select a rank of countries based on number of medals won by measuring the number of Gold(3), silver(2), Bronze(1) from the table below:

```
+-----------+-------------+--------+-----------------+----------------------------+-------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------+
| idRESULTS | STATUS      | MEDALS | EVENTS_idEVENTS | EVENTS_ATHLETES_idATHLETES | EVENTS_ATHLETES_TEAMS_idTEAMS | EVENTS_ATHLETES_TEAMS_COUNTRY_idCOUNTRY | EVENTS_VARIOUS_SPORTS_SPORTS_ID | awarded_medals_medal-id |
+-----------+-------------+--------+-----------------+----------------------------+-------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------+
| results1  | DID-NOT-WIN | SILVER | TEN             | MS                         | RUS-WTA                       | RUS                                     | WOMENS_TENNIS                   |                       2 |
| results1  | WON         | GOLD   | TEN             | VW                         | USA-WTA                       | USA                                     | WOMENS_TENNIS                   |                       3 |
| results2  | DID-NOT-WIN | BRONZE | ATH             | JG                         | USA-TF-MEN                    | USA                                     | TRACK-AND-FIELD                 |                       3 |
| results2  | WON         | GOLD   | ATH             | UB                         | JAM-TF-MEN                    | JAM                                     | TRACK-AND-FIELD                 |                       1 |
| results3  | WON         | GOLD   | TEN-DOUBLE      | SW                         | USA-WTA                       | USA                                     | WOMENS_TENNIS                   |                       3 |
| results3  | WON         | GOLD   | TEN-DOUBLE      | VW                         | USA-WTA                       | USA                                     | WOMENS_TENNIS                   |                       1 |
+-----------+-------------+--------+-----------------+----------------------------+-------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------+
```

I have this code below but this does not produce the expected output?

```
select EVENTS_ATHLETES_TEAMS_COUNTRY_idCOUNTRY,MEDALS
 from results
 group by EVENTS_ATHLETES_TEAMS_COUNTRY_idCOUNTRY
```

Answer (score 0):

try this!

```
select EVENTS_ATHLETES_TEAMS_COUNTRY_idCOUNTRY, rank() over (Order by Score desc) as Ranking
from
(
    select EVENTS_ATHLETES_TEAMS_COUNTRY_idCOUNTRY, sum(
        case when MEDALS='GOLD' then 3 --assigning gold a value of 3
        when MEDALS='SILVER' then 2 --assigning silver a value of 2
        when MEDALS='BRONZE' then 1 --assigning bronze a value of 1
        end) as Score
    group by 1
) Scores
```

The major thing you were doing in the first one was just pulling all the unique combos of EVENTS_ATHLETES_TEAMS_COUNTRY_idCOUNTRY and MEDALS, which wouldn't be assigning a score. if you're interested in ranking by each one separately, you can change the values in the case when accordingly.

Comment: This code seems fine but somehow i get a syntax error when i run? i am using mysql?

Comment: i think you need EVENTS_ATHLETES_TEAMS_COUNTRY_idCOUNTRY in the group by

Comment: The compiler lists the syntax error as being near the 'over (Order by Score desc) as Ranking' ?